# Dividing express routes among Node JS Clusters

Tags: node.js, multithreading, express, nginx

I have a large set of routes in a Node JS application I'm trying to scale to multiple CPU cores (via NodeJS clusters).

The plan I had in mind was to have different workers handling a different set of express.js routes. For example:

```
/api/ requests handled by WorkerA
/admin/ handled by WorkerB
/blog/ handled by WorkerC
etc
```

Simply using a conditional with the worker ID is not sufficient, since requests can still land at the wrong worker. Also, the processes all run on the same port, so I can't just match & proxy_pass on the URL from inside nginx.

At this point, I'm thinking about swapping out the cluster routing (from master to worker) to match on the URL and route to the correct worker instead of just using the built-in round-robin approach. But this seems a bit hacky and I'm wondering if anyone else has solved this, or might have any other idea.

Comment: Did you guys revisit this and find any other options? Was hoping to handle this with a combination of routes and the cluster module

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to run multiple express apps listened on different ports, and set a Nginx server at front to proxy requests

Say you have three express apps, each one would handle a specific type of routers, and listen on separate port (`8081`, `8082`, `8083`), and of course, they should run in cluster mode:

```
//API app used to handle /api routing
apiApp.listen(8081);

//Admin app used to handle /admin routing
adminApp.listen(8082);

//Blog app used to handle /blog routing
blogApp.listen(8083);
```

And config the Nginx server to proxy the requests:

```
server {

    # let nginx server running on a public port 
    listen       80;

    location /api {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081
    }

    location /admin {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082
    }

    location /blog {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8083
    }
}
```

`proxy_pass` simply tells nginx to forward requests to /api to the server listening on `8081`. You can check the full document [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

Comment: So annoying but I guess it's the only option :|

Comment: Did you guys revisit this and find any other options? Was hoping to handle this with a combination of routes and the cluster module. @Antoine