# routing incoming request between nodejs processes

Tags: node.js

I have an app that it's logic is based on data that stored in an object . object **state**  change with each request .
I have multiple of this object in my app and I need to implement clustering for performance . is there any way that I can route incoming request to a specific worker that
hold one of my objects that requested object is in that

```
                                                   worker A (hold object `a` in it's memory)
                                           |-------worker B (hold object `b` in it's memory)
request to object B  ---> primary cluster -|       worker C (hold object `c` in it's memory)
                                                   worker D (hold object `d` in it's memory)
```

Comment: Maybe this can give some idea..(this from 2017 though) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477109/dividing-express-routes-among-node-js-clusters

Comment: Usually, the way this is done is by storing all the object data in a redis instance (in-memory database) and then all clustered server instances can access the same data store so any cluster instance can serve any data.  The redis instance handles the concurrency between the various servers (assuming you use concurrency safe access techniques).  Otherwise, you have to create some scheme by which you can know which server process contains a given object so you can manually route the request to the appropriate server process.  At large scales of data, you use a disk-backed database.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.